# Species identification - greenish blue ocean worm (nudibranch?) in Perhentian Islands, Malaysia

Tags: zoology, species-identification, marine-biology, invertebrates

We found this on a beach at the Perhentian Islands, Malaysia in March, 2016 and cannot identify it.  It's some sort of worm-type creature with many legs and bluish back about 15cm long.  The legs undulated along the body as it swam.

back:

[image: sea millipede]

belly side:

[image: sea millipede underneath]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to identify from the photos provided, but I think it is [*Chloeia flava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloeia_flava) (a species of [polycaete worm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychaete), within the phylum Annelida), also known in English as the "Golden Fireworm".
The size is roughly similar to what you describe (they are typically about 7-10 cm long). The individual you observed looks like it lives in sandy bottom environments (not a typical environment for a nudibranch), and this worm does also. It is commonly found all across the warmer Indo-Pacific as well, and looks like the individual observed in your photo.

If it is not this species, I think it is another species of the same family, Amphinomidae.

[image: Chloeia flava]

Comment: Thanks! We're happy to have seen a nudibranch in real life.  We just learned about their existence a few months ago when a blue dragon washed up in Australia.  We're lucky we weren't stung by this one since we were swimming very close to it to study it.

Comment: Sorry my answer was edited. It is not a nudibranch or mollusk but a polycaete worm. If you want to find a nudibranch I recommend checking tidal pools or near coral. If you aren't a diver yet, the best way to observe them is to take up scuba diving.

Comment: :( So not a nudibranch but still very interesting.

Comment: Sorry for my mistaken edit. My mind was so set on a nudibranch that I didn't even spot the mistake even though I visited the wikipedia page for *C. flava*.

Comment: @fileunderwater No problem! Thank you for the edit. It was my first post and I learned how to format posts now.

Comment: @Sudachi Welcome to BioSE! [Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) is a useful overview of html/markdown formatting at SE.